# Calling method of derived class on object of base class

Tags: c++, linux, inheritance, gcc, vtable

I have written a few lines of code which I think should not compile. I am calling a method of a derived class on a static_cast-ed pointer to object of base class as follows:

```
class B {};    

class D: public B
{
public:
    void bar() { printf("%d\n", m_i); }
private:
    int m_i;
};

int main()
{
    B b;
    D* d = static_cast<D*>(&b);
    d->bar();
    return 0;
}
```

The value printed is obviously junk but should this even compile? How does `gcc` manage to do that?

Comment: Why shouldn't it compile? You're casting the B as a D. For all the compiler knows, it's doing operations on a D

Comment: please don't use printf in C++ code.

Comment: @BatchyX: `printf` may be hideously unsafe, but it IS substantially faster than `cout` and friends.

Comment: @BatchyX: Nothing wrong with printf() if used correctly.

Comment: Well, try mixing printf with cout in a portable program, and see what happen. no "correct usage" of printf will fix that. As for performances, just enable optimization and the difference between printf and cout will be zero if you don't flush every output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gcc` can't guarantee that it's incorrect, except in enough of a minority of cases that it really isn't worth checking. When you use `static_cast`, then you are promising the compiler that you know wtf you're doing.

There are two kinds of casts here. `static_cast`, which is, you are telling the compiler that pointer to a base IS a pointer to derived, and shut up and get on with it. `dynamic_cast`, which is, you are asking the compiler to check if that pointer to base is indeed a pointer to derived. You used `static_cast`, so the compiler shut up and did as you said.

Edit: John accurately pointed out that there are no virtual functions in your inheritance hierarchy, for which you should be fired from C++, and `dynamic_cast` is only valid for virtual functions.

Comment: `dynamic_cast` won't work in this partucular case because the types are not polymorphic.

Comment: @John: Good point. Why do people keep posting code involving inheritance and no virtual functions?

Comment: Ok. Got it. Stupid question. And at runtime, it probably prints the contents of the location in memory where the variable m_i would have been had the object been on class D. Right?

Comment: @DeadMG: Absence of virtual functions is what confused me. I thought static_cast-ing involves some sort of check unlike the reinterpret-cast or C cast.

Comment: @314008: Yes. Why would you think that? `static_cast` is just that- static.

Comment: I remembered reading that somewhere. Went back and saw that all it does is check that the classes are related. Again, my bad; stupid, stupid question.

Answer (score 0):

Using the static_cast<> you told the compiler "I know what I am doing, that B* is actually D*, shut up and just do what I say."

Comment: Not exactly.  `static_cast` won't compile unless the two types are related.  Perhaps you're thinking of `reinterpret_cast`

Comment: @John Dibling: Within certain compile time checks, using static_cast<> you are telling the compiler `I know better than you`. As a result you better be doing it correctly.

Comment: @John Dibling: did I say otherwise?